# ansible aws_s3 module Access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ansible

I would like to give access to a path of a AWS s3 bucket but not to the root path.. And here is the bucket policy I'm using for that:

```
        {
        "Sid": "OrgListObjects",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucketVersions",
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "s3:prefix": [
                    "sso/infra/auth/*",
                    "sso/infra/auth"
                ]
            },
            "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
                "aws:PrincipalOrgPaths": "**hidden**/*"
            }
        }
    }
```

This is working as awaited :

```
$ aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket/sso/infra/auth
   PRE ...list of data...
$ aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket/
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
```

However is there a way to make `head-bucket` succeed ?

```
$ aws s3api head-bucket --bucket my-bucket
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
```

I'm asking that because ansible module [amazon.aws.aws_s3](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/aws_s3_module.html) uses `head-bucket` to check the access of a bucket (even if it could access to a sub path of it...). So maybe another solution could be to bypass that check somewhere in the module ?

Fyi, here is the ansible playbook

```
- name: Setup ssh access
  block:
  - name: get a list of authorized users from s3
    local_action:
      module: amazon.aws.aws_s3
      profile: master-profile
      bucket: my-bucket
      prefix: oceasoft/infra/auth
      mode: list
    register: ssh_users
    run_once: true
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The fine manual for [`ignore_nonexistent_bucket:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/6/collections/amazon/aws/aws_s3_module.html#parameter-ignore_nonexistent_bucket) says:

> Overrides initial bucket lookups in case bucket or iam policies are restrictive. Example: a user may have the GetObject permission but no other permissions. In this case using the option mode: get will fail without specifying ignore_nonexistent_bucket=true.

Which seems to be confirmed by [the source](https://github.com/ansible-collections/amazon.aws/blob/4.1.0/plugins/modules/s3_object.py#L1070)

Comment: Thks for your answer, however, this does not solve the problem. I'm suspecting a bug in the aws_s3 module. I've opened it here : https://github.com/ansible-collections/amazon.aws/issues/966

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I only checked the top of the method, but thank you so very much for opening the issue and I hope they merge the fix soon